# Quarkus : Converting existing spring application

Tags: quarkus

Can someone share the experience of converting existing spring application to Quarkus

Existing spring application has dependencies with 1) Swagger 2) Oracle Jdbc Driver 3)Logging framework 4) Spring auto wiring

Answer (score 4):

It depends if you want to generate native executable or not.

In JVM mode:

- we have a Swagger extension based on OpenAPI that gets you the Swagger UI in dev mode (https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui-guide). If you want to use Swagger itself, well, you should be able to include it without any issue.
- the Oracle JDBC driver should work out of the box
- logging wouldn't be an issue. We come with JBoss Logging which has several adapters for other frameworks.
- we have a Spring compatibility extension for autowiring that translates the Spring annotations to CDI: https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-di-guide

And then, there's the GraalVM native executable mode. And then comes the bad news: I don't think the Oracle JDBC driver will work for now. We don't have an extension for it and I'm pretty sure it won't work out of the box for now.

But Quarkus has benefits even in JVM mode, so it would be worth it anyway.

If you start this journey, we're interested in feedback, either on the mailing list or in GitHub issues.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. 
One step at a time. To focus on JVM Mode - Does it support spring JDBC template as well ?

Comment: No, the only Spring functionality supported (for the time being) is Spring DI annotations.

Comment: @geoand is there an easy way to achieve that in Quarkus world, if it doesn't support SpringJdbcTemplate (which help avoid database connection boilerplate code)

Comment: Hibernate/JPA is supported out of the box. There is also Hibernate Panache that simplifies DB access even more